# Elmah (mvc4) ignores the customErrors (but it logs)

Tags: web-config, asp.net-mvc-4, elmah

I've just migrated a MVC3 project to a 4.

I also installed the newest update of ELMAH.

I do have an issue with unhandled exceptions.

In my web.config I have this:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/Error/Error" redirectMode="ResponseRedirect">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/NotFound" />
</customErrors>
```

When I get an unhandled exception, Elmah logs it, no problem there, but it doesnt send me to the Error/Error view. It also doesn't do the 'ResponseRedirect'

What it does instead is keep the URL as it was, and it shows me the Error.aspx view from the Shared folder.

How do I change the settings somewhere, that the customErrors won't be ignored?

Comment: You are using the `[HandleError]` attribute in your controller, aren't you?

Comment: No I haven't used `[HandleError]`

Answer (score 2):

If you are seeing the `Error.aspx` page then definitely `HandleError` filter is playing behind it. Go to `Global.asax.cs` and check `HandleErrorAttribute` is not added in the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method.

Also make sure you haven't overridden the `OnException` method of the controller and doing something manually yourself.

Comment: I have commented out the `//filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());` but this didnt fix my problem

Comment: also, this worked perfectly in MVC3, i only migrated to 4. so must be something with that.